# How to disable/stop certain logs in error.log file (XAMPP, Apache, Win7)?

Tags: apache, xampp, httpd.conf

Sample from my "error.log"

[Fri Sep 23 10:20:25.512713 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4288:tid 260] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

[Fri Sep 23 13:32:53.988274 2016] [core:warn] [pid 4028:tid 248] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

[Fri Sep 23 13:32:55.049076 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4028:tid 248] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.6 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Fri Sep 23 13:32:55.049076 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4028:tid 248] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39

[Fri Sep 23 13:32:55.049076 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4028:tid 248] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'

[Fri Sep 23 13:32:55.049076 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4028:tid 248] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4264

[Fri Sep 23 13:32:55.813477 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4264:tid 260] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

I already set ( LogLevel error ) to my httpd.conf

But I still get this error log every time I restart our Webserver. In my opinion, these logs are not actually errors but only notices and warnings. Since we restart our webserver 3 times a week, our error log file will grow bigger in filesize as the days go by.

I searched on the internet and stackoverflow but I cannot find what Im looking for. Or maybe I overlooked it, I dont know.

Anyway, I do not know what else I need to do to stop this logging to error.log file as Im not expert on this.

Thanks in advance for your help.